# Memorising Depth of Recursive Function Inside Class

Tags: algorithm, class, python-3.x, recursion, depth

In order to make my small script working i need to memorise the depth of each recursive function inside a class.

Suppose we have a list of dependencies like this:

```
package1:
package2: package1
package3: package1 | package2
```

Which simply means that `package1` depends on nothing, `package2` depends on `package1` and `package3` depends on `package1` **or** `package2`.

I have found problems while trying to implement a counter inside a class.
The recursive part consist in entering the current node (`self`), incrementing the counter by 1, calling the previous node and so on until the top of the graph. I need to count the depth because in the **or** i need to choose the package with less dependency needed, in this case `package1` since it has no dependencies.

What i tried are the following operations:

```
class Node:
...
counter = 0
def dep_resolve(self, resolved, unresolved):
    unresolved.append(self)
    counter += 1
    for edge in self.edges:
        if edge not in resolved:
            if edge in unresolved:
                raise Exception('Circular')
            edge.dep_resolve(resolved, unresolved)
    resolved.append(self)
    unresolved.remove(self)
```

the same but with the counter outside the Class;

```
counter = 0
class Node:
...
```

and with the counter as global variable. But I still get errors((ie.`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment`))

Is there correct way to memorise the dependency in a class?

Comment: i think it would solve your problem to pass the counter as an argument into the recursive function. you can then e.g. assign it to a local variable or do something else with it

Comment: Did you mean [memoize or memoise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might tackle this problem in a different location.

Your packages and dependencies is basically a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)), where the packages are vertices and the dependencies are edges.

Your approach is basically doing a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on this graph, which is fine, and can find the depth of each package (though if it's not a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) - you might find a depth which is not the shortest one).

Another approach, which is designed to find the "shortest path" (or minimal depth in your case) is running a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), instead.

This is very easy to maintain the current depth of a BFS, and all packages that are of depth `k`, will be developed together in the algorithm, so it's pretty easy to find the depth using this approach.

python-like Pseudo code for the BFS approach:

```
q = new queue
q.add((source,0))
visited = {}
visited[source] = 1
while not q.empty():
    (curr,d) = q.poll()
    for each dependency (curr,next):
        if next not in visited:
             visited[next] = 1
             q.add(next,d+1)
             #the depth of next is d+1, do something with it
```